# Connecting a PyQt5 application to another python program

Tags: python, sockets, oop, pyqt5

I have separately developed programs for a pyqt5 app and a client for communicate with a server.

GUI:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from screen_stack import Ui_MainWindow_screenstack
from screen1 import Ui_Form_screen1
from screen2 import Ui_Form_screen2
from screen3 import Ui_Form_screen3
from client_cli_oop_with_exception_printing import mainProg

import socket
import threading #maybe this won't useful
import sys
import os

class MainApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__()  #if init was provided with paren=None, then inside this init parent argument can be passed
        self.screenstack = Ui_MainWindow_screenstack()
        self.screenstack.setupUi(self)
        self.screen1 = scr1()
        self.screen2 = scr2()
        self.screen3 = scr3()
        self.screenstack.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.screen1)
        self.screenstack.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.screen2)
        self.screenstack.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.screen3)
        
        self.screenstack.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.screen1)
        # self.screen1.s1.connect_tcp.clicked.connect(
            # lambda: self.screenstack.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.screen2)
        # )
        self.screen1.s1.connect_tcp.clicked.connect(self.init_connect_server)
        self.screen2.s2.register_name.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.screenstack.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.screen3)
        )
        
        self.sock = None
        self.errScr1 = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
        self.errScr1.setWindowTitle('Error')
        
    def init_connect_server(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            self.sock.connect((self.screen1.s1.tcp_link.text(), int(self.screen1.s1.tcp_port.text())))
            self.screenstack.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.screen2)
        except Exception as e:
            self.errScr1.setText(str(e))
            self.errScr1.exec_()

    def start_client_threads(self):
        #all the communication threads should start here..
        pass
            
      
class scr1(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(scr1,self).__init__()
        self.s1=Ui_Form_screen1()
        self.s1.setupUi(self)
class scr2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(scr2,self).__init__()
        self.s2=Ui_Form_screen2()
        self.s2.setupUi(self)
class scr3(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(scr3,self).__init__()
        self.s3=Ui_Form_screen3()
        self.s3.setupUi(self)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    sw = MainApp()
    sw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Client:

```
import socket
import threading
import time
import os

class mainProg:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.is_connection_lost = threading.Event()
        self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            self.client.connect((host, port))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Server is not valid...quitting...')
            time.sleep(5)
            os._exit(0)
            
        self.start_threads()
        
    def recieve(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = self.client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if message == 'Nickname':
                    self.client.send(nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                elif message == '': #when server gone, we will recieve a lot of empty strings continuously.. we can make the clients shut the python if server gone, but client waiting server to init again will be cooler
                    self.is_connection_lost.set()
                    self.client.close()
                    print('Connection Lost: waiting for the connection,')
                    while True:
                        print('waiting...')
                        time.sleep(3)
                        if not self.is_connection_lost.is_set():
                            print('Connection restored!!!')
                            break
                        
                    
                else:
                    print(message)
                    #print(type(message))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                print('An error occured!, Not yet connected!')
                #client.close()
                #is_connection_lost = True
                break
        
    def send_messages(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = f"{nickname}: {input('')}"
                self.client.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
            except Exception:
                pass
                
    def reconnect_server(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        while True:
            if self.is_connection_lost.is_set():
                print('Trying to connect!!!!')
                time.sleep(3)

                self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                try:
                    self.client.connect((srv,port))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Reconnect failed due to {e}')
                    continue
                if self.client.recv(1024).decode('utf-8') == '':
                    self.client.close()
                    pass
                else:
                    self.client.send(nickname.encode('utf-8'))
                    self.is_connection_lost.clear()  #no problem here, it connects to server when server is up again...
                
    def start_threads(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.recieve)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.send_messages)
        t3 = threading.Thread(target=self.reconnect_server)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t3.start()
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nickname = input('Choose a nickname: ')
    
    srv = '0.tcp.in.ngrok.io'
    port = 14112
    mainProg(srv, port)
```

I know that using qthreads I can rewrite the code for client in GUI and make a functional app. But   is there a way to connect both classes, so that I can use *self.labelMessage.setText(message)* instead of *print(message)* in client. In another way I am asking is there a way to inherit from multiple classes (MainApp and mainProg) so that I can easily connect both codes?

Comment: While not completely impossible, doing it without QThreads would probably just complicate things more than they already are. With QThreads you can use signals and the problem is solved. Note that Qt provides [QTcpSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html), which already has an asynchronous API.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. So as you say I can completely replace sockets with QTcpSocket?

Comment: Well, it depends on your needs, but if you don't have a very specific case, it's normally enough. I suggest you to study the documentation and try some basic tests.

Comment: For communication between applications, all you need is [QLocalServer/Socket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalserver.html). This would be much simpler to set up than your example.